# Construct Query with Linq rather than SQL strings

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I've got a 2.0 server control that uses a dynamic query roughly in the form:

```
string sql = "Select " + columnvariable + " FROM " + tablenamevariable
```

So, obviously, you could give it any valid column name from any valid table in the DB and it would return the values in the column into a DataReader (in this case).

I'm trying to cut down on the amount of explicit piecemeal SQL in the codebase and would prefer to do this in LINQ. Is there an easy way to do this? Is it even advisable? I suppose that the resulting piecemeal SQL in this case would be so generic as to not really pose a security problem in this instance.

Even so, it seems like some fairly basic functionality so I'm curious. I've got as far as including System.Linq.Dynamic in my project but this seems to stop shy of allowing a programmer to dynamically select which table they want a dynamic column from.

I don't mean this to be a discussion. I'd like an answer like "Yes, this is possible and trivial, here's how..." or "Yes, but only if you construct this elaborate set of handler classes and basically rewrite parts of LINQ, here's how..."

I would, however, be interested to know whether people think doing this kind of thing in LINQ could best be described as a) a jolly good idea or b) crazy talk.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6273d072-f500-4382-afb4-8eafd185794d

Comment: LINQ to SQL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Comment: not exactly what I was thinking... maybe an example would serve..

Comment: It's probably a good idea to get rid of this where possible.  Have you considered what will happen if, eg through malicious user input, `tablenamevariable` becomes `" myTable; DROP TABLE ReallyImportantTable;"`. Read up on SQL injection.

Comment: @Winston: This is a very good point. The risk of this kind of injection is minimal as the data would be input through the configuration properties of a bespoke server control which would only be accessible to technical staff at our organisation. By the time someone with access to the control wanted to do something like that there would be simpler, and more devastating, ways for them to do it. Even so... I would rather be safe than sorry if I could be. Hence the original question. So far I have to ask "What other option do I have?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were looking for a straightforward answer ... No, this is not possible in LINQ.

LINQ is inherently strongly typed, while you're looking for something entirely dynamic.  If your table and column are runtime variables (i.e. strings) then your SQL will need to be a string ... or you would need to use an ORM (NHibernate, L2S, EF, etc) to access the data.

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes I'm coming to that conclusion. But thankfully I'm learning a bunch as I do.

Answer (score 0):

This entry in Rick Strahl's blog seems to be talking some kind of sense on this topic:

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/314663.aspx

In the absence of anything even clearer I think I shall make my choices based on that.

Any other potential answerers should be thinking about whether their potential answer is any clearer than the above link. If not, then it would probably be a waste of your time getting involved.

EDIT: Although this is linked to in the above mentioned article this:

http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/ShowPost.aspx?id=134706

clarifies my issue perfectly and is, in fact, a sort of prequel to the other article. Fascinating stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from good ol' Scott Gu(thrie):

[Dynamic LINQ, Part 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: That was one of the first articles I saw. Unfotunately I need to be able to dynamically select the table as well as the column(s) I want from the table. In the example article the query is restricted to the products table.

Comment: Upvote for pasting the top result of a Google for "Dynamic LINQ" that doesn't even offer a solution to one of the fundamental issues in the original question? Nice work if you can get it...

Comment: Seriously?  You ask for help, and then berate answers from people trying to help you?  Probably won't help your cause in the future...

Comment: Strictly speaking didn't help my cause right now, either. I opted out of my named account precisely because of the bizarre and arbitrary nature of the voting system in this place. I'm not criticising you for posting a lazy answer per se I'm criticising whichever twonk decided that it was any more helpful than my own answer which seriously considers all aspects of the issue. You do deserve more kudos than the guy who posted something which just plain doesn't work though, I will admit.

Comment: Well, the Dynamic LINQ article is a start ... making it work for your scenario will take a bit more effort and information, but giving a downvote for it is uncool, especially since a lot of people don't even know about Dynamic LINQ so it's reasonable to assume that you don't know anything about it.

Comment: Good job I can't downvote then. But to be fair in the original text of the question I reference adding System.Linq.Dynamic into my project so anyone reading the actual question can see I am aware of the Dynamic Linq library. With so many really fascinating and useful answers I felt it unfair that this should receive an upvote when the others were ignored.

Comment: @bert - when I provided my answer, it was the first one posted.  I did read that you added the reference, but I actually had no idea whether you read the Scott Guthrie article or not, or even knew what that reference was for.  I've seen plenty of questions from people who have added libraries they thought they needed, or didn't know they needed but took a shot in the dark, or...  Just because the answer you provided to your own question did not get an upvote, it does not mean that this was a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this from the wrong angle.  You think you want this:

```
void DoStuff(tablenamevariable, columnvariable)
{
    string sql = "Select " + columnvariable + " FROM " + tablenamevariable 
    // read data 
}


DoStuff("MyTable", "MyColumn");
```

By why that interface?   What wrong with this:

```
void DoStuff<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
      // read data
}


DoStuff(from t in MyTable select t.MyColumn);
```

This still defines the table & column in the calling function, but with better type safety & flexibility.  For example, you could now include a Where clause if needed.

```
DoStuff(from t in MyTable where t.OtherColumn == 5 select t.MyColumn);
```

Comment: This is good stuff. I wish I could vote it up. One major question though. is the argument to DoStuff in your second example a string? or a bald statement? I intend to run along now and have a look into this IQueryable interface so the answer may be there. But anyhow, this is far more helpful. Will be even more so if I can get it to work as intended in my app!

Comment: It's not a string, it's a bald statement (expression actually). With strings, if you wrote "MyTabel" you won't find the error until run-time.  My way, you see the error at compile time.

Comment: That's no doubt going to save me some trouble at some other time but right now it's becoming apparent that L2S is not the tool for this job. Still, the IQueryable interface is new to me and looks like it will come in handy so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question doesn’t clarify where exactly the `columnvariable` comes from, but if I’m allowed to make the following assumptions, then I think I can provide you with a near-trivial solution:

- Assumption 1: The `columnvariable` is a value that is passed around through method calls, but ultimately it is a constant. I.e. it is not a user-provided string, it is not read from a file, etc.
- Assumption 2: You have access to all the code that passes in those constants for a `columnvariable`.

If these assumptions hold, then my recommendation is to change your method that contains this:

```
string sql = "Select " + columnvariable + " FROM " + tablenamevariable
```

into something more like this:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers<T>(Expression<Func<Customer, T>> column)
{
    return db.Customers.Select(column);
}
```

and then instead of

```
// Assuming "CustomerName" is the name of a column in the Customers table
var myCustomers = GetCustomers("CustomerName");
```

you would say

```
// Properly type-safe and compile-time checked
var myCustomers = GetCustomers(c => c.CustomerName);
```

Comment: I think possibly this would have benefitted from some clarification. Essentially I am making a server control which presumes the person using it is familiar with the DB Schema of the underlying DB. So you have a server control tag that takes the table and column as properties. These should then access the relevant data and return it. LINQ doesn't seem to be the tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to be completely dynamic, i.e. you could have any string for the table name and the column name, then I suspect your only option is to construct an expression tree manually. Something like...

```
public IQueryable<TResult> GetColumn<TResult>(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    // Get the table, e.g. for "Customers" get db.Customers
    var table = db.GetType().GetField(tableName).GetValue(db);

    // Find the specific type parameter (the T in IQueryable<T>)
    var iqueryableT = table.GetType().FindInterfaces((ty, obj) => ty.IsGenericType && ty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>), null).FirstOrDefault();
    var type = iqueryableT.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // Construct a query that retrieves the relevant column
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type);
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, columnName);
    var expression = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);

    // Call Queryable.Select() with the appropriate parameters
    // Notice there are two Select methods, need to get the right one...
    return (IQueryable<TResult>) typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(meth => meth.Name == "Select")
        .Select(meth => meth.MakeGenericMethod(type, typeof(TResult)))
        .Where(meth => meth.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(TResult))))
        .First()
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { table, expression });
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
var customerNames = GetColumn<string>("Customers", "CustomerName");
```

Of course you still need to know the type of the column because you want it to return a properly strongly-typed queryable. Alternatively, you could add an `Expression.Convert` if you want it to automatically convert *all* data to strings; then you don’t need to specify the `string` every time, but of course your column data will be converted to strings potentially lossily.

Comment: Holy expletive! That is a really useful piece of code right there. I think it's going to take me a few days just to unpick all the stuff that's going on in there. I am definitely going to have to give this a go at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Your query:

`string sql = "Select " + columnvariable + " FROM " + tablenamevariable`

can be 'translated' with LINQ like this:

`var sql = (from tablenamevariable select columnvariable).ToList();`

and now the 'sql' variable contain the list of 'columnvariable' stored in 'tablenamevariable'.

You can make it much simple with LINQ.

Comment: I would love it if that worked but it doesn't. At least not as a direct cut and paste job.