# Linq: Dynamic Query Contruction: query moves to client-side

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, lambda, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I've been following with great interest the converstaion here:

[Construct Query with Linq rather than SQL strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769141/construct-query-with-linq-rather-than-sql-strings)

with regards to constructing expression trees where even the table name is dynamic.

Toward that end, I've created a Extension method, addWhere, that looks like:

```
static public IQueryable<TResult> addWhere<TResult>(this IQueryable<TResult> query, string columnName, string value)
{
    var providerType = query.Provider.GetType();
    // Find the specific type parameter (the T in IQueryable<T>)
    var iqueryableT = providerType.FindInterfaces((ty, obj) => ty.IsGenericType && ty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>), null).FirstOrDefault();
    var tableType = iqueryableT.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var tableName = tableType.Name;
    var tableParam = Expression.Parameter(tableType, tableName);
    var columnExpression = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(tableParam, columnName),
        Expression.Constant(value));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda(columnExpression, tableParam);
    var function = (Func<TResult, Boolean>)predicate.Compile();
    var whereRes = query.Where(function);
    var newquery = whereRes.AsQueryable();
    return newquery;
}
```

[thanks to Timwi for the basis of that code]

Which functionally, works.

I can call:

```
query = query.addWhere("CurUnitType", "ML 15521.1");
```

and it's functionally equivalent to :

```
query = query.Where(l => l.CurUnitType.Equals("ML 15521.1"));
```

ie, the rows returned are the same.

However, I started watching the sql log, and I noticed with the line:

```
query = query.Where(l => l.CurUnitType.Equals("ML 15521.1"));
```

The Query generated is:

```
SELECT (A bunch of columns)
FROM [dbo].[ObjCurLocView] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CurUnitType] = @p0
```

whereas when I use the line

```
query = query.addWhere("CurUnitType", "ML 15521.1");
```

The query generated is :

```
SELECT (the same bunch of columns)
FROM [dbo].[ObjCurLocView] AS [t0]
```

So, the comparison is now happening on the client side, instead of being added to the sql.

Obviously, this isn't so hot.

To be honest, I mostly cut-and-pasted the addWhere code from Timwi's (slightly different) example, so some of it is over my head. I'm wondering if there's any adjustment I can make to this code, so the expression is converted into the SQL statement, instead of being determined client-side

Thanks for taking the time to read through this, I welcome any comments, solutions, links, etc, that could help me with this. And of course if I find the solution through other means, I'll post the answer here.

Cheers.

Comment: The fact that you have `Compile` in there should be a big red flag to indicate that it can't run on the DB server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem is that you're converting the expression tree into a delegate. Look at the signature of [`Queryable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) - it's expressed in expression trees, not delegates. So you're *actually* calling [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) instead. That's why you need to call `AsQueryable` afterwards - but that doesn't do enough magic here. It doesn't really put it back into "just expression trees internally" land, because you've still got the delegate in there. It's now *wrapped* in an expression tree, but you've lost the details of what's going on inside.

I suspect what you want is this:

```
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, Boolean>>
      (columnExpression, tableParam);
return query.Where(predicate);
```

I readily admit that I haven't read the rest of your code, so there may be other things going on... but that's the core bit. You want a strongly typed expression tree (hence the call to the *generic* form of `Expression.Lambda`) which you can then pass into `Queryable.Where`. Give it a shot :)

Comment: Alright, I removed the compile part, so the code now looks like: